# Ошибка в коде Swift3

Tags: xcode, swift

раньше строчка работала сейчас выдает ошибки, как ее изменить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста приводите код и ошибку в виде текста, а не на скриншоте.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уберите круглые скобки в условии `for` циклa.

```
for i in 0 ..< count {
}
```

Comment: а такую строчку?   `for(i: CGFloat in 0 ..< 3){`

Comment: Объясните мне смысл вот этого: i: CGFloat in 0 ..< 3? Зачем указывать i как float, если она у вас int? Сами подумайте, вы можете пройти цикл 2.3 или 1.8 раз?